# ghostpcl mswinpr2

Tags: printing, gdi, ghostscript, printer-control-language

I am having difficulties to print a pcl file to a gdi printer via ghostpcl. On some forums a suggested solution is to set mswinpr2 as the output device. This should produce GDI output for a windows printer. The problem is, there seems to be no mswinpr2 built into ghostpcl. When running ghostpcl -? there is no such device listed. Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version you are using, but for me the executable is called pcl6.exe, not ghostpcl. In any event the mswinpr2 device is not built into the PCL interpreter by default. While it may work with the PCL interpreter, it depends how the device was written. If you want to use it you'll have to build GhostPCL from source.

Comment: Do you by any chance know what I need to change in the source files to include mswinpr2? And which compiler to use for a windows build?

Comment: GhostPDL on Windows uses Microsoft Visual Studio, though other compilers may well work. Although it is supplied with a VS project it actually uses nmake to compile, other make utilities might well work. TO add mswinpr2 you would need to change the makefiles, I'm not certain what would need to be changed, but I added the display device myself in the past and it wasn't outrageously difficult. THe sources don't need to change, you just need to include the device in the build. You can probably get some clues by looking at the GS makefiles, which already include it.